# Android Holo theme can't be applied on one of my activities

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an issue where my Theme.Holo can't be applied on my Initial activity and there's still the old styles from the old theme. When I run the application on my device the theme is already applied (no problems) but I the xml Design is still the same as before. Any ideas? Here is the code of xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".InitialActivity"
android:id="@+id/initialActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/first_button"
    android:id="@+id/firstButton"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="223dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/second_button"
    android:id="@+id/secondButton"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirdButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/third_button"
    android:id="@+id/thirdButton"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tabata_button"
    android:id="@+id/tabataButton"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/firstButton" />
```

And my values' styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".InitialActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FightActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fight"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.stambeto09.muaythai_timer.FightActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TabataActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tabata"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.stambeto09.muaythai_timer.TabataActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

P.S The other two activities are render perfectly on both device and design of xml.

Comment: What does your AndroidManifest.xml look like?

Comment: @alanv I've just added it.

Comment: The <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="xx" /> tag seems to be missing.